# strongly typed enums in g++-4.4

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, strongly-typed-enum

According to the [GCC C++11 support status website](http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html), strongly typed enums are available for `g++4.4` and greater.

However the following does not compile with `g++4.4`:

```
enum class Foo
{
   value_1,
   value_2
};

int main()
{
   Foo a = Foo::value_1;
   Foo b = Foo::value_2;
   const bool test = ( a < b );
}
```

The error message is `error: invalid operands of types ‘Foo’ and ‘Foo’ to binary ‘operator<’`.

Compilers that accept the code include `g++-4.6`, `g++-4.7`, `g++-4.8` and `clang++ 3.2`. ( I couldn't test with `g++-4.5` as I don't have it installed currently (and Ubuntu 13 doesn't want me to))

I could easily provide a fallback for this (rather old) compiler with a macro, but I generally dislike that (where does it stop?...).

What's the problem here? Is the information of support wrong or is another bit missing that's not included in "support for strongly-typed enums"? Last option I can think of: Is the problem in my code?

Comment: for production code, my recommendation would be not to use C++11 features on versions prior to at least 4.7 and preferably not prior to 4.8. If you insist on supporting multiple compiler versions *and* you want to use C++11 features, you quickly become the g++ bug database maintainer. Ubuntu 13 does provide g++ 4.7 out of the box, and there is a ppa for g++ 4.8

Comment: Well it's working fine except for this tiny bit. I know, I'd rather have range-based for loops everywhere, but it's a trade-off between nice features and compatibility.

Comment: +1 for the self contained example and research effort. Sadly this seems to be the exception for SO questions.

Comment: If you are going to use C++11 features on compilers that pre-date C++11, you have to expect features that are not the same as described in the standard due to both (a) changes to the feature between the experimental implementation and the final standard, and (b) plain old-fashioned errors in implementation (that's what "experimental" means).

Comment: @Casey Well according to the official website _all_ versions of GCC have "experimental" C++11 support only. But if a the website claims support for a feature for versions "X and above", I'd expect it working with these versions. Otherwise what's the point of that list?

Comment: The page does not claim that the implementations of those features are bug-free. Indeed, [here's the bug about comparison operators not working with `enum class`](http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38064) that was fixed in 4.5.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a *known* bug. As @Casey found out, originally `g++-4.4` did not support any relational operations on strongly-typed enums. For *equality*, this was fixed in version `4.4.1`, but the fix for all other relations such as `<` and `>` only made it into `4.5.1` and above.

This is the original bug thread on the gcc bugzilla: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=38064